# Running cmd as administrator scala

Tags: windows, scala, hadoop

i have a cmd command i want to execute it from scala langauge as administrator.Here the code i used:

```
 val p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -windowstyle hidden  C:\\Hadoop\\Hadoop-2.3\\sbin\\start-dfs.cmd -verb RunAs")
```

It runned but not as administrator .
Thank youu for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this suggestion: https://superuser.com/questions/42537/is-there-any-sudo-command-for-windows#42540

So,

```
val p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("runas /noprofile /user:Administrator C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -windowstyle hidden  C:\\Hadoop\\Hadoop-2.3\\sbin\\start-dfs.cmd -verb RunAs")
```

Comment: @Evengy Nothing happened  i think there is a problem here  /noprofile /user:Administrator what is the exact information i should put

Comment: @MaherHTB can you just run JVM as administrator? Then your `exec()` from question should work.

Comment: the code is running from eclipse scala ide , i am exporting my app to a jar and the same problem here Thanks

Comment: @MaherHTB how do you execute your app from jar? Have you tried to invoke it from cmd with `runas /noprofile /user:Administrator java -jar path_to_jar main_class`?